# Is Groovy 2.2 broken for argument parsing with -n?

Tags: groovy, command-line-interface

This is sort of obscure, but I can't figure it out.

I have a program that uses Groovy's CliBuilder to parse command line options.  Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
args.each { println it }
def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: '...usage...')
cli.n(args: 1, 'The name')
def options = cli.parse(args)
println ":" + options.n
```

I run the program with:

```
groovy test.groovy -n name
```

Using Groovy 2.1.7, I get the expected response:

```
-n
name
:name
```

Using Groovy 2.2.2, I get something strange:

```
?
name
:false
```

This only happens when using -n as a command-line option.  I don't know if it conflicts with Groovy's own -n option or not.  It doesn't seem to in 2.1.7.  Using -n also breaks any subsequent options passed on the same command line.

Is this a bug?  Is the workaround just to avoid -n?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Replicable in 2.2.1 as well. Log one [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY/fixforversion/19075).

Comment: Looks like something broke in the Groovy upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2. That's the upgrade where Traits were announced but pulled at the last moment because making a release date just before a big conference was more important than having some features in the release, or even keeping a feature that worked it seems.

Comment: This looks it was broken at least in `Groovy Version: 2.1.1`. Just tested with the currently latest `Groovy Version: 2.3.7` and it still doesn't work. I guess this bug sums everything up nicely: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6090.

Comment: Updated link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6090